# How to remove duplicate any string beginning and ending with quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below string in javascript:

```
var str = '"restoreState":                     "restoreState":0,';
```

the duplicate sub-string is `"restoreState":`. I want to use regex to remove the duplicated sub-string. I tried below code but didn't work:

```
var re = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/, '')
console.log(re)
```

the output is `"\"eState\": \"restoreState\":0,"`.
How can I remove that by regex? what wrong with my regex?

I am looking for a solution for general strings. Remove the duplication part of the string if it has one otherwise dont' do anything on the string. For examepl:

`"restoreState":  "restoreState":0,`   => `"restoreState":0,`

`"restoreState": 0`  => `"restoreState": 0`

Comment: What if the string is `"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"`? Should anything be done? What if the string is `"foo": { "foo": "bar" }`? What if it's `"foo": "bar": "foo": "bar": 0`?, what about `"foo": "baz", "bar": "baz"`?... The question is too vague to answer.

Comment: yes, all cases will be considered as duplicate. In the case of `"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"`, I expect the result is `: , "bar": "foo"`. Remove the first match substring.

Comment: Another question is, you seem to be fine with `:` and `,` being duplicated. Is the criterion "any string beginning and ending with quotes"? How about `"foo": 17, "bar": 17`? Is there a duplicate there?

Comment: Oh, you mention a good point. I should say "any string beginning and ending with quotes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on question comments:

```js
function dedupe(str) {
    return str.replace(/("[^"]+")(?=.*\1)/g, '')
}
console.log(dedupe('"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"'));
console.log(dedupe('"foo": { "foo": "bar" }'));
console.log(dedupe('"foo": "bar": "foo": "bar": 0'));
console.log(dedupe('"foo": "baz", "bar": "baz"'));
console.log(dedupe('"foo": 17, "bar": 17'));
```

Capture the string: quote, any number of non-quotes, quote. Make sure there's another one later. If so, replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`([a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!.*\1\b)`

This should remove you duplicate words with alpha chars

Comment: this also removes normal string. Take this string as an example: `"restoreState":0,`, the output after replace is `"\"\":0,"`. I want to remove the duplication part on the string.

Comment: @ZhaoYi Show us the _whole_ input string and the _whole_ expected output string. It seems to me that Tim's answer is correct based on what you've said so far.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question about this.